# Cucumber/Capybara - The use of doubles or partial doubles from rspec-mocks outside of the per-test lifecycle is not supported

Tags: cucumber, capybara, stub

I know that we generally don't want to stub a method in acceptance/feature tests, but this is something I ABSOLUTELY need to stub for all of my acceptance/feature tests.

When I put the stub call in `Before` block in env.rb or in a `Background` step, I get the following error.

```
The use of doubles or partial doubles from rspec-mocks outside of the per-test lifecycle is not supported. (RSpec::Mocks::OutsideOfExampleError)
```

Where should I put the stub call so that it will work in all scenarios?

Answer (score 5):

I thought this might work:

```
  RSpec::Mocks.with_temporary_scope do
    allow_any_instance_of ....
  end
```

Documented here:

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/scope

but actually does not work as I expect - better solution is:

```
require 'cucumber/rspec/doubles'
```

thanks to Sanjay! @sanjsanj

Documented here:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Mocking-and-Stubbing-with-Cucumber

Comment: It looks like documentation for this is falling out of date? This doesn't work for me :(  BUT adding the with_temporary_scope bit did the trick!!!  Thanks!